# local ring all whose non-maximal ideals are finitely generated

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules, local-rings

Let $(R, \mathfrak m)$ be a commutative local ring such that every non-maximal ideal is finitely generated. Then, is $R$ Noetherian i.e. is $\mathfrak m$ finitely generated ideal ?

It is easy to see that the answer is yes when $R$ is integral domain by considering an ideal $r\mathfrak m$ for $r\in \mathfrak m $ and noting $r\mathfrak m\ne \mathfrak m $ and $r\mathfrak m \cong \mathfrak m$ (as $R$-modules) .

If $\mathfrak m$ is not finitely generated in a ring as above, then $\mathfrak m$ is an $R$-module all whose proper submodules are finitely generated, so from [1](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0021869383900753/1-s2.0-0021869383900753-main.pdf?_tid=40dd23e0-afc5-4c52-b27f-df58928e4322&acdnat=1528634237_54e7eb164e9628fbab29c68b9a8c7e8a) (Proposition 1.1, Proposition 1.3 ) and [2](http://www.mscand.dk/article/viewFile/11699/9715) (Proposition 1.2) , one can see the following : $ann_R (\mathfrak m)$ is a prime ideal, $\mathfrak m$ is divisible as $R/ann_R (\mathfrak m)$-module and it is either torsion-free or every element is a torsion. The ring (possibly non-commutative) $End_R (\mathfrak m)$ is local i.e. the set of non-units forms an ideal. Also, $Ass_R (\mathfrak m)=\{P\}$ is singleton and that single associated prime is the set of all zero-divisors of $\mathfrak m$ . If the associated prime ideal is $P=ann_R (\mathfrak m)$, then $\mathfrak m$ is torsion-free over $R/ ann_R (\mathfrak m)$ and in that case $\mathfrak m $ is isomorphic to the fraction field of $R/ann_R (\mathfrak m)$ as $R$-modules and $ann_R (\mathfrak m)$ is not maximal and $\mathfrak m$ is not Artinian as  $R$-module. If $ann_R(\mathfrak m) \notin Ass_R(\mathfrak m)$, then the associated prime ideal is maximal and every proper non-maximal ideal of $R$ has finite length, so in particular $\mathfrak m$ is an Artinian $R$-module. In any case, $ann_R (\mathfrak m)$ is not a maximal ideal.

1. [Modules Whose Proper Submodules Are
   Finitely Generated, 
   WILLIAM D. WEAKLEY](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0021869383900753/1-s2.0-0021869383900753-main.pdf?_tid=40dd23e0-afc5-4c52-b27f-df58928e4322&acdnat=1528634237_54e7eb164e9628fbab29c68b9a8c7e8a)
2. [Rings with an almost Noetherian ring of fractions,Efraim Armendariz](http://www.mscand.dk/article/viewFile/11699/9715)

Comment: If there a non-noetherian example, there's either a reduced one (=with no nonzero nilpotent element) or a "purely nilpotent" one, in the sense that the nilradical is a maximal ideal. If you can exclude one of these it would be worth mentioning.

Comment: Also, does the existence of a non-noetherian examples implies that of a local one?

Comment: @YCor: So by purely nilpotent you actually mean $R$ is zero-dimensional right ? ... how did you conclude that a non-noetherian example would be one of those kind ? And I didn't get your second comment ... all my rings are local ..

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the local assumption. Yes purely nilpotent is equivalent to being local of Krull dimension zero. The reduction is as follows: if $A$ is an non-noetherian example to your question, if the nilradical is maximal we're done; otherwise it's finitely generated and hence in the quotient by the nilradical, the maximal ideal is still infinitely generated (while other ideals are finitely generated).

Comment: But now thinking twice this is useful, because if $R$ is not zero-dimensional, it has a nonmaximal prime ideal, and taking the quotient yields a domain example. You've already observed there are no such examples. Therefore the only potential examples are 0-dimensional.

Comment: PS you seem to have excluded this latter case. I'll try to get the whole picture and post an answer.

Comment: @YCor: ah yes you are right ... so we are only to consider zero-dimensional case ... but you see if $\mathfrak m$ is not f.g. then $ann_R (\mathfrak m)$ is not maximal but prime ideal , so we cannot have zero-dimensional counterexample ...

Comment: @YCor : so any such ring is always Noetherian ...

Comment: @YCor Please note this preprint: https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.03735 submitted to the arxiv on Sun, 10 Jun 2018 22:23:38 GMT — just a few hours after your answer here. I'm not sure what's going on...?

Comment: @ZachTeitler thanks very much for pointing out. The OP possibly ignores that copying others' arguments without a reference is considered as plagiarism.

Comment: @YCor: I would like to point out here that none of the arguments given in the arxiv e-print is the same argument as that of your answer ...

Comment: @users solving a mathematical problem when you know the answer beforehand is often easier. In this case nothing is hard and indeed there are many ways to reach the conclusion, and visibly you didn't manage to do so by yourself. Second, part of the argument in the arxiv paper is on the non-local case, where you essentially copy my account of Keith's argument.

Comment: @YCor: Note also that the references in the arxiv preprint are essentially the same as the references in the problem statement on the current page. Looks very fishy.

Comment: @ZachTeitler thanks very much for your worthwhile information. A discussion can be found on meta: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3798/deleted-answered-question-arxiv-posts-based-on-unacknowledged-mo-posts

Comment: @YCor I am not quite sure what is your point in "solving a mathematical problem when you know the answer beforehand is often easier". That is true, but what does "nothing is hard" mean then? If Faltings proves a theorem in $p$-adic Hodge theory and then Beilinson proves the same theorem in a different way, does his paper necessarily contain nothing hard? An alternative argument for the same theorem can be both helpful and hard to find, from my understanding.

Comment: @schematic_boi I agree my formulation might have sounded ambiguous. When I said "**in this case**", I didn't mean "in the case when you know the answer beforehand". I meant, **in the precise case in consideration** (the question by the OP, the MO answer and the subsequent arxiv papers).

Comment: @YCor ah OK then, I totally agree.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There exists no such non-noetherian local ring.

Below I assume by contradiction that we have such a ring.

(a) The first observation is a particular case Proposition 1.2(a) in your reference to Armendariz: for every $r\in R$, we have $r\mathfrak{m}\in\{\mathfrak{m},\{0\}\}$. Indeed, $r\mathfrak{m}$ is a quotient of $\mathfrak{m}$; if it's nonzero, it's quotient by a proper submodule and hence is also not noetherian, which implies $r\mathfrak{m}=\mathfrak{m}$.

(b) case when $R$ is a domain (I just expand your argument). Choose $r\in\mathfrak{m}\smallsetminus\{0\}$. Since $R$ is a domain, by (a) we have $r\mathfrak{m}=\mathfrak{m}$, and in particular so $r\in r\mathfrak{m}$, and since $R$ is a domain this implies $1\in\mathfrak{m}$, a contradiction.

(c) let us check that $R$ is necessarily of Krull dimension 0. Indeed if $P$ is a nonmaximal prime ideal, then $P\neq\mathfrak{m}$ and hence is finitely generated, so $R/P$ is a counterexample to (b).

(d) Now we use Proposition 1.2(b) in Armendariz: $P=\mathrm{Ann}_R(\mathfrak{m})$ is prime (as you've already mentioned). The argument is easy: indeed, for $x,y\notin P$, by (b) we have $x\mathfrak{m}=y\mathfrak{m}=\mathfrak{m}$, which implies $xy\mathfrak{m}\neq 0$, so $xy\notin P$.

(e) Combining (c) and (d), the only option for $\mathrm{Ann}_R(\mathfrak{m})$ is that it's equal to $\mathfrak{m}$. Thus $\mathfrak{m}^2=\{0\}$. Then $\mathfrak{m}$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space over the field $R/\mathfrak{m}$, and all its hyperplanes are ideals. In particular they fail to be finitely generated, and this is a contradiction.

---

*Edit 1:* the argument can be extended to show that there is no commutative ring at all with these conditions (non-noetherian such that all non-maximal ideals are finitely generated). That is, assuming $R$ local is unnecessary. In other words, a commutative ring is noetherian if and only if all its non-maximal ideals are finitely generated ideals.

Indeed, (a),(b),(c),(d) work with no change for every given infinitely generated maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Let us adapt (e):

(e') for every infinitely generated maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, by combining (c) and (d), its annihilator is another maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}'$. Then $\mathfrak{m}$ can be viewed as a $R/\mathfrak{m}'$-vector space. Hence the lattice of ideals contained in $\mathfrak{m}'$ can be identified to the lattice of $R/\mathfrak{m}'$-vector subspaces of $\mathfrak{m}$. In particular, the condition that all its elements except whole $\mathfrak{m}$ are noetherian, implies that $\mathfrak{m}$ has finite dimension (as vector space over $R/\mathfrak{m}'$), hence is finitely generated as an ideal, a contradiction. We deduce every maximal ideal is finitely generated, and hence (since all non-maximal ones are also finitely generated by assumption) that $R$ is noetherian.

---

*Edit 2:*

As mentioned by Keith in the comments, the non-local case can be handled in an even easier way:

let $R$ be a ring (commutativity is unnecessary) in which every non-maximal left ideal is finitely generated, and having at least two maximal left-ideals. If $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal left-ideal and $\mathfrak{m}'$ is another one, then $\mathfrak{m}\cap \mathfrak{m}'$ is finitely generated, and $\mathfrak{m}/(\mathfrak{m}\cap \mathfrak{m}')\simeq (\mathfrak{m}+\mathfrak{m}')/\mathfrak{m}'=R/\mathfrak{m}'$ is a simple module, so $\mathfrak{m}$ is also finitely generated.

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't get why is $\mathfrak m$ infinite dimensional over $R/\mathfrak m$ and the subsequent hyper-plane argument you make ... you could also use Proposition 1.3 of Weakley's paper that if $\mathfrak m$ is not finitely generated then $ann_R (\mathfrak m)$ is not maximal , but we know it is prime , so there can be no zero-dimensional counterexample.

Comment: The argument for domains I had in mind is like this (very similar but not by contradiction ) : If $\mathfrak m=0$ we are done. O.w. take $0\ne r \in \mathfrak m$ . Then $r \mathfrak m=\mathfrak m$ implies $r=rx$ for some $x \in \mathfrak m$ , then $x=1$, impossible ! So $r \mathfrak m$ is not maximal , hence finitely generated and moreover since $R$ is a domain and $r \ne 0$, we get $r\mathfrak m \cong \mathfrak m$ is f.g.

Comment: @users right, taking the square is useless, I removed it. It's the same argument up to frills.

Comment: Curious about the meaning of the downvote.

Comment: Can drop the assumption that $R$ is local: If $R$ is a commutative ring whose non-maximal ideals are f.g., then $R$ is Noetherian. The local case is handled above. If not local, and $M, N\lhd R$ are distinct maximal ideals, then $M$ is f.g. over $M\cap N$, which is f.g.

Comment: @KeithKearnes I've already dropped the local assumption (see the edit) by essentially the same argument as in the local case. My first approach was more similar to yours, but I don't see right away why $M/(M\cap N)$ is finitely generated.

Comment: $M/(M\cap N)\cong (M+N)/N$ is a simple $R$-module.

Comment: @KeithKearnes thanks indeed. As I said, the non-local case was already covered, but this argument shows that the non-local case is even more trivial.