# Rings with all non-prime ideals finitely generated

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules, local-rings, prime-ideals

Motivated by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302468/local-ring-all-whose-non-maximal-ideals-are-finitely-generated), I would like to ask:

> If all non-prime ideals in a ring are finitely generated, then is the ring Noetherian? Can we at least say anything in the local case?

Note that for zero-dimensional rings, the answer is yes by the linked question. So we only need to think about rings of positive dimension.

NOTE: All our rings are commutative with unity.

Comment: you have erased your subsequent question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304492/reduced-ring-with-all-non-prime-ideals-finitely-generated after it's been answered (with a significant effort for the answerer to reply it); this is considered as incorrect behavior and you should undelete it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

If $\mathbb Z_{p^{\infty}}$ is a Prufer group for prime $p$, then its endomorphism ring is isomorphic to the ring $\mathbb Z_p$ of $p$-adic integers. Hence $\mathbb Z_{p^{\infty}}$ is a $\mathbb Z_p$-module, and we can form the idealization $R:=\mathbb Z_p\oplus \mathbb Z_{p^{\infty}}$. The ideals of this ring are known: they are of the form $0\oplus H$ for a subgroup $H\leq \mathbb Z_{p^{\infty}}$ or of the form $(p^k)\oplus \mathbb Z_{p^{\infty}}$ for some nonnegative integer $k$. 
(See Example 1 of Paul A. Froeschl, Chained rings. Pacific J. Math.
Volume 65, Number 1 (1976), 47-53.)
In particular, $R$ is a local ring with exactly one non-finitely generated ideal $I:=0\oplus \mathbb Z_{p^{\infty}}$. This ideal is prime because $R/I$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_p$, a domain.

Comment: I see ... thanks ... do you have any local domain counterexample ? Or to ask more ... a Valuation ring counterexample ... ?

Comment: It would be reasonable to ask about a domain in a separate question.

Comment: There is no domain counterexample. I will explain this at the other question.

Comment: yes ... the answer is trivially silly for domains ...

Comment: In domains, $ r \notin rI$ for every $0\ne r \in R$ and every proper ideal $I$ of $R$. Now if $0\ne P$ is prime ideal and $0\ne r \in P$ then $r^2 \in rP$ but $r \notin rP$   , so $rP$ is not a prime ideal hence f.g. hence $rP \cong P$ (as $R$-modules) is f.g.

Comment: We are really only using that every non-zero prime ideal contains a non zero divisor ...

Comment: Oh, it's indeed very simple. Maybe one could ask about reduced rings.

Comment: @YCor : yeah ... reduced ring case seems to be difficult ..

Comment: Reduced case is here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304492/reduced-ring-with-all-non-prime-ideals-finitely-generated

Comment: Reduced case was deleted by its original poster, then reposted by me here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304533/reduced-ring-with-all-non-prime-ideals-finitely-generated

Comment: By the way it works with $\mathbf{Z}_p$ replaced with $\mathbf{Z}$. It works for such a ring $R\oplus M$, where $M$ is an $R$-module, $R$ noetherian, such that $rM=M$ for every $r\in R\smallsetminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @YCor: "it works" -- except for the local part of the question.

Comment: Indeed, you're right.